# How can I sort my Schema by author to get latest entry for all users?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I'm working on a Facebook clone and on my `index` page I want it to where it shows the most recent status update of each friend.

Here's my User Schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, "can't be blank"],
    match: [/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, "is invalid"],
    index: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, "can't be blank"],
    match: [/\S+@\S+\.\S+/, "is invalid"],
    index: true,
  },
  password: String,
  email: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  friends: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
});
```

and my Status Schema

```
const statusSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  author: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

**What I've tried**

In my `index.js` file I wrote this code to give the most recent status update

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Status.find({}, "content author createdAt")
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .limit(1)
    .exec(function (err, recent_status) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.render("index", { author: req.user, recent_status: recent_status });
    });
});
```

And inside my `index.ejs` file I have this bit of code

```
<%= recent_status[0].content
```

That shows the most recent status update inside the Status Schema array but I'm trying to get the most recent status for each user and can't figure it out.

Comment: I would suggest looking into the aggregate and group functions for mongodb, and using something like [{ $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },{
      $group: {
        _id: "$author",
        recent_status: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
      }
    }]


useful docs can be found here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/
and here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/